# Load balancing with gRPC subchannels in C#

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, grpc

I'd like to do simple client side load balancing for grpc as [described here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/load-balancing.md).

I'm using Microsoft Azure Service Fabric so getting a list of the available endpoints is trivial, but I can't find an API to add sub-channels to the C# `Channel` class. Is adding sub-channels possible with the C# client? If not what would be the best solution for implementing this.

Answer (score 2):

If you set

```
channelOptions.Add(new ChannelOption("grpc.lb_policy_name", "round_robin"));
```

the GRPC C# client will automatically open subchannels for each A record that's resolved by the DNS request, and will route across them appropriately.

A good example of GRPC loadbalancing in C# (although for Kubernetes, not service fabric) is [this example repo](https://github.com/jtattermusch/grpc-loadbalancing-kubernetes-examples) from Jan Tattermusch's Kubecon talk a few years ago.

Comment: I'm not using DNS to resolve. I've got a service that returns a list of IP/Port pairs. Is there any way to make that work?

Comment: Ah - based on [this doc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/naming.md#detailed-design) you can likely use `ipv4:address[:port][,address[:port],...]` as an argument to the [Channel](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Channel.cs#L66) constructor since C# uses the core implementation internally.